# Layer symbology not displaying in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

This screenshot is when world imagery layer is turned on but my shapefile is only displaying the YSUBuildings layer.
[image: This screenshot is when world imagery layer is turned on but my shapefile is only displaying the YSUBuildings layer.1]]

I'm creating a shapefile by outlining buildings on a base map, I've outlined several buildings now I am labeling other types of buildings but the symbology won't display for them. Yet when you click on them it displays the outline I drew and the information.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Do you have symbology defined for the layer? Can you select the features even though they don't display?

Comment: We would definitely need to see your symbology properties as @User2009 requested and probably the attributes of at least one of the features that isn't drawing to even have a guess at why Arc is being mischievous.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the symbology tab on the Layer Properties. Then click the Add Values button where you'll be able to select the category for the buildings you've created.

Sorry, I'm not on a computer with ArcGIS at the moment so I can't show screenshots.

Comment: Are you referencing layer properties out of the table of contents?

Comment: That's correct. You control symbology from there.